# CKEditor 4 in Vue - how to prevent word breaking?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

In my Vue project I have a CKEditor. The problem with it is that it breaks words instead of breaking spaces:

[image]

In code inspector it looks like this:
[image]

I can't find a way to make it break on spaces instead of words. I tried to put `white-space: nowrap;` on the body (in the debugger, just to see if it works), but it just made all this text appear in one line. `word-break: keep-all;` didn't do anything.

One thing I must notice - I don't have defined width on the editor component. It just uses all available space.

Is there anyway to still make it break white spaces instead of words? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found sort of a solution, perhaps could be useful to somebody. The issue is with `&nbsp;` entities. Basically CKEditor creates one very long string, which doesn't have spaces. I solved it by running the following method, which replaces all the `&nbsp;`s with regular spaces, on every content change and passing the content as argument:

```js
const removeNBSP = (text: String) => {
  return text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ")
}
```